# Can we use selectors as cases in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a function with switch inside which will use cases. As cases I'll have `'#a li' '#b li' '#c li' '#d li'`
If #a/b/c/d li clicked, it will check screen width (for responsiveness), and if it is less than 990 it will show modal #amodal #bmodal and etc, depends on which # is clicked.
How to turn it into one function with switch and cases?

**Jquery:**

```
   $('#a li').click(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 990) {
    $('#amodal').modal('show');
    }
});
$('#b li').click(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 990) {
    $('#bmodal').modal('show');
    }
});
$('#c li').click(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 990) {
    $('#cmodal').modal('show');
    }
});
$('#d li').click(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 990) {
    $('#dmodal').modal('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: Just do `$("#a li, #b li, #c li, #d li")`, and let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, Jquery [doc](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$("#a li, #b li, #c li, #d li").click(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 990) {
       // if parent: $(this).parent().attr("id")
       $("#" + $(this).attr("id") + "modal").modal('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: It's a different modal in all four of the cases, this only shows `#dmodal`

Comment: The ID is not on `this`, it's on the `li` that contains it.

Answer (score 0):

If `#a, #b , #c , #d` is not a parent of `li` you shoud use [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find what modal to open

```
$('#a li , #b li , #c li , #d li').click(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 990) {
        $('#'+$(this).closest("#a , #b , #c , #d").attr("id")+'modal').modal('show');
    }
});
```

If `#a, #b , #c , #d` is a parent of `li` use [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
$('#a > li , #b > li , #c > li , #d > li').click(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 990) {
        $('#'+$(this).parent().attr("id")+'modal').modal('show');
    }
});
```

I prefer to add class as a selector and use it

```js
$('.open_modal > li ').click(function () {
    console.log("Modal to open:" + $(this).parent().attr("id"));
    /*if ($(window).width() < 990) {
        $('#' + $(this).parent().attr("id") + 'modal').modal('show');
    }*/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="a" class="open_modal"><li>Test A</li></ul>
<ul id="b" class="open_modal"><li>Test B</li></ul>
<ul id="c" class="open_modal"><li>Test C</li></ul>
<ul id="d" class="open_modal"><li>Test D</li></ul>
```